# Avoid data-binding for a variable in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, forms, data-binding, binding, vue.js

I have a simple form asking for username and password. 
Those are my Vue.js data

```
  data: {
    app_images:[
      { app: '../assets/img/logos/logo.png' }
    ],
    json_repository:[],
    user: {
      username: null,
      password: null
    },
    submitted: null
  }
```

Username and password field in the form are bound to user.username and user.password. Pressing a sign in button execute doLogin function

```
methods: {
  doLogin: function() {
    this.submitted = this.user;
},
```

Problem is that from this moment on, every edit in the form also change the value in "submitted" field and i want to avoid that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a copy of your data to avoid this issue.

```
methods: {
  doLogin: function() {
    this.submitted = Object.assign({}, this.user);
},
```

Now your `this.submitted` and `this.user` are no longer referring to the same object and changing one will not change the other.

Comment: Fast as a rabbit and fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign({}, object) is not working properly when you have multiple inner objects. I solve this problem with store object before change as string with JSON.stringify and then rollback object with JSON.parse like...

```
this.beforeEditingCache = JSON.stringify(this.editObject);
```

and on cancel

```
this.editObject = JSON.stringify(this.beforeEditingCache);
```

you can use this in edit data in forms and rollback data if cancel the edit.